# Can't upload multiple files using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, multer

I am unable to select and upload multiple files using Multer in Node.js.

I was able to do a single file upload in a different exercise without any issue, but now I am stuck on multiple uploads function.

What am I mistaking? How can I make it so that the user can select and upload multiple files? Thank for help.

**This is my form:**

```
<form class="form" action="/file" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input type='file' name="upload" class="form-control"/>
  </label>
</div>
<input id="submit" type='submit' value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

**My backend code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const multer = require('multer')
var fs = require('fs');

// SETUP PACKAGES

const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads' }) ;

// SETUP MIDDLEWARE

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(fileUpload());

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// DECLARE UPLOAD DIRECTORY

const uploadDirectory = __dirname + path.sep + 'uploads'

// DECLARE PROMISES

const writeFile = (name, body) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.writeFile(uploadDirectory + path.sep + name, body, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                } else {
                        resolve(name)
                }
            })        
    }).then(readFile);
}

const readFile = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile(uploadDirectory + path.sep + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                } else {
                        resolve(data)
                }
        })
    })
}

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/file', upload.array('upload', 5), (req, res) => {

    if(req.files.upload instanceof Array){ 
        for (var i = 0; i < req.files.upload.length; i ++ ){
            let name = req.files.upload[i].name;
            let data = req.files.upload[i].data;
            let write = writeFile(name, data);

            console.log(req.files.upload[i].name);

            write.then(()=> res.end('fileS uploaded'))
            .catch((e)=> res.status(500).send(e.message));

        } 

        }else {

            // let name = req.files.upload.name;
            // let data = req.files.upload.data;

            // writeFile(name, data)

            // res.end("file uploaded")

    }
    });

    app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: refer to this tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/multiple-file-upload-node-js/ also you can just search google for multiple fileupload with multer you will get multiple tutorials like this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the "multiple" attribute in your input tag. Without specifying that, the input field will send the last file you upload to your backend and thus only one file would get uploaded.